# How to turn unsigned ints into signed ints in x86 assembly? (Using c functions)

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm, signed

I am trying to read a binary file's content as signed ints, but `fread` keeps interpreting them as unsigned.

I am reading the file using the `fopen` function from within x86 assembly code:

```
    mov  rdi, file      ;;File is entered as input before
    mov  rsi, mode      ;;mode db "rb",0
    sub  rsp, 8
    call fopen
    add  rsp, 8
    mov  [handle], rax  ;I save the file handler in a variable
```

Said file, contains numbers stored in binary, one next to the other. If you read the file you  see: `..2`
Using a hex editor, we see that those numbers are:

| Hex | Sign 8 bit value in base 10 |
| --- | --- |
| CA | -5 |
| 90 | -1 |
| 32 | 50 |

Later I want to read byte by byte each value stored:

```
    mov  rdi, number
    mov  sil, 1         ;;Each number is 1 byte in size
    mov  rdx, 1
    mov  rcx, [handle]
    sub  rsp, 8
    call fread
    add  rsp, 8
    cmp  rax, 0
    jle  EOF
```

That part is successful and I manage to save CA in the number variable. However, the debugger tells me that the number variable's value is: 202

Which is CA's UNsigned value. So I tried using `sscanf` to turn it into its signed counterpart:

```
    mov  rdi, number
    mov  rsi, signed    ;; signed db "%hhi",0 (As I understand it, this represents the 8 bit signed format)
    mov  rdx, numberInt
    sub  rsp, 8
    call sscanf
    add  rsp, 8
```

Yet, this does not work, seen in how the RAX register returns a 0 value and the number still evaluates to 202.

Comment: Assembly has no concept of sign.  The value is the same. Only the signed operations treat them differently.

Comment: Apart from a few instructions, assembly has no concept of signed or unsigned integers. They are a construct of a higher level language. Processor flags are set after instructions, and the programmer or the  compiler chooses which flags to test (which branch instruction to use), depending on whether they are dealing with signed or unsigned values.

Comment: If you want to sign extend use instruction movsx

Comment: A C cast is a no-op on a 2's complement machine.  Use the bit-pattern unchanged; that gives C's semantics of modulo-reduction into the value-range for unsigned to or from signed integer.  (If you're widening a signed byte to an int, load it with `movsx eax, byte [rdi]` or whatever, instead of `movzx`).   In your case, the only thing you're doing wrong is changing the code instead of changing how your debugger prints it (or reinterpreting in your head.)

Comment: The debugger has to convert the bit pattern to something we can understand.  That bit pattern can be in decimal as signed or unsigned, or in hex, or in binary, or as an ascii number.  The output format doesn't change the numbers value.

Comment: How does: 0xCA relate to -5; 0x90 to -1?  (0x32 is 50, but I don't see the relation with the others.)  FYI 0xCA as unsigned decimal is 202, and as signed decimal is -54.

Comment: @PeterCordes 8bits to 32 bits signed is definitely no no-op as it has to be sign extended

Comment: @0___________: Yes, I should have said a C cast between integer types of the same width is a no-op on a 2's complement machine.

Comment: @Crazy: Note that if you want one byte at a time from C stdio functions, usually either `fread` into an array and loop over it, or call `fgetc` to return a byte zero-extending into EAX (or `-1` EOF on error).  It's easier to call, only taking one arg, the `FILE*`.  `fread` for one byte at a time is the worst of both for convenience, although at least for efficiency it's not making a system call for every byte like if you used `read` directly.  `fgetc_unlocked` would be fast-ish if you don't want to fread into an array but still care at all about performance.

Comment: @PeterCordes, only in the presence of optimization is such a cast a no-op.  For example by the language rules, a variable of unsigned char, when used in an expression is instantly automatically cast to `int` width, so would be zero extended; if then cast to (signed) char, would be truncated to 8 bits, then instantly automatically re-widened to `int` width/type, which would cause sign extension.  If the user cannot notice this, say because the value is then assigned to a (signed or unsigned) char variable, then of course, optimization allows those widening and shortenings to be elided.

Comment: @ErikEidt: If you have a `signed char sc`, and you do `(unsigned char)sc`, you don't have an `int`.  If you do almost anything with that `unsigned char` result of the cast, yes it will get promoted to `int` (e.g. use it with any arithmetic operator), but not if you  `unsigned char uc = (unsigned char)sc`, unless I'm mistaken.  And even if there's technically a promotion to int and back in there somewhere in the C abstract machine, it's not useful to think about it when trying to understand how asm works.  Also, integer promotions only happen for narrow types, not `unsigned` or `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 1):

Example in C

```
    char ch;
    int i;

    fread(&ch, 1, 1, stdin);

    i = ch;

    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

and generated code:

```
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR stdin[rip]
        mov     edx, 1
        mov     esi, 1
        lea     rdi, [rsp+15]
        call    fread
        movsx   esi, BYTE PTR [rsp+15] <<<<<<<<<< 
------------------------------------------------
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
```